# Accelerometer sensor gives too low value:

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to work with the accelerometer sensor as my phone doesn't have the linear version of it, i read the android developer documentation of the sensor, and he mentioned here the following

> For this reason, when the device is sitting on a table (and obviously not accelerating), the accelerometer reads a magnitude of g = 9.81 m/s^2

However, when the phone is sitting o a table, it doesn't give me this value, instead, it gives me low values like "1.2"

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i got it, it's because i was logging the acceleration in x-axis, and the gravity should be in y-direction which points upward

Comment: can anybody explain to me why it gives values continuously